# How to append schema name in the SQL generated by fastnate

Tags: java, jpa

I am using [fastnate](https://fastnate.org/) to generate some static data. My entities have the `@Table` annotation on them with the `schema` property. For example `@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "general")` like so. However, the generated insert queries do not have the schema appended to them. My expectation is the generated SQL should look something like `INSERT INTO general.PERSON(...) VALUES...`, however the generated SQL is like `INSERT INTO PERSON(...) VALUES...` like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for Fastnate < 1.5.0, you can read about it [here](https://github.com/liefke/org.fastnate/wiki/FAQ#which-jpa-features-are-supported):

> Some remarks:
>
> - The schema and catalog attributes are ignored for all ...Table annotations for versions before Fastnate 1.5.0

So you should use version 1.5.0 or later.